# multiple data table toggle column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
     } );
      var table = $('#example2').DataTable( {
      });

     $('input.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); //empêche la mise à jour des check

    // Get the column API object
     var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );



} );
```

My event "input.column-toggle" works only for my last table (example2) ...

How can I do for the event work for all my a.column-toggle class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `table` variable to find the column inside the table. But you've assigned two things (example1 and example2) to the same variable in successive statements. Therefore example2 has replaced example1 in the `table` variable. You've lost the information that relates to example1.

You need two variables, table1 and table2. And then perform the column hiding operation on both.
e.g. something like (I haven't tested it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var table1 = $('#example').DataTable( {
     } );
      var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable( {
      });
     $('input.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {

    // Get the column API object
     var column1 = table1.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
     var column2 = table2.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    // Toggle the visibility
    column1.visible( ! column1.visible() );
    column2.visible( ! column2.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

Or, if you need to do this on several tables, or want to add more tables flexibly in future, you might want to consider creating an array of tables and then looping through the array, performing the same actions on each element.

Comment: Ok i get it, i thought i had to use the table ID !!
It was friday, my brain gived up, thanks a lot